# Python sqlite3 cursor has no attribute commit

Tags: python, sqlite

When I run this code:

```
path = '~/Scripts/wallpapers/single.png'
conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/Heaven/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db')
cur = conn.cursor();
cur.execute("insert into data values ('" + path + "');")
cur.commit()
```

I receive the following error

```
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

and I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: That is entirely correct. Did you meant `conn.commit()` instead? :-)

Comment: Please use `cur.execute("insert into data values(?)", path)`, or do _really_ trust that filenames will _never_ contain a `'` character? (Users can be tricky…)

Comment: This will show you the possible commands for connection and cursor. Check that you did not misspell or mix them: print("Connection functions:",dir(sqlite3.connect('::memory::'))) print("\n\n") print("Cursor functions:",dir(sqlite3.connect('::memory::').cursor()))

Answer (score 25):

`commit()` is a member method of `sqlite3.Connection` not `sqlite3.Cursor`. Here it is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit).

Answer (score 12):

From the answer from sir_charles804 (sorry not enough points to add this as comment) follows it should be:

```
conn.commit()
```

instead of

```
cur.commit()
```

Answer (score 11):

It's

```
conn.commit()
conn.close() //if you intend to close it afterwards
```

Explanation:
The cursor is only used to pass instructions to sqlite, while you have to commit or close with the instance you've made to connect to your database.

Comment: Technically, it's because transactions are a feature of the connection overall, and not a cursor. There are cases where it makes sense to have multiple cursors open at once within a single transaction.